# Is it more efficient to perform analytics on database data in memory or with repeated queries?

Tags: sql, database, performance, analytics

I'm trying to developing complex analytics for data stored in a typical distributed database (no HDFS or anything like that). At this point I'm not sure of the database, but assuming the analytics could be completed either with complex sequences of queries or by copying the dataset entirely into memory and working on it from there, which is more efficient?

In short, if the choice is between running the analytics in SQL and copying the entire dataset to memory and running analytics from there, which would be faster/more efficient/less overhead/etc.?

If it helps:

- The dataset is a few tens of GB in size
- The data is distributed
- The machines can handle the memory requirements without issue

Comment: The database(s) will (hopefully) have the data in cache so I assume network speed/latency will be the limiting factor. Choose the solution with the smallest network requirement. (unless your analytics requires calculations which are difficult to express in set based SQL)

Answer (score 1):

Depends entirely on what you are going to do with the data.

If you are going to touch most of the data, you might do it locally. A small subset is likely to be better dealt in SQL if the problem can be expressed in SQL.

Teoretically you could make it more efficient by pulling all the data in local memory, but you need to organize it in trees, tries and maps properly. Just pulling the data in and looping it through is going to be slow unless the problem requires touching all of the data anyway.

If the SQL server has enough memory, the data is going to cached anyway and the database servers tend to know how to index and access the data efficiently.